# Android ML Text Recogniser is not returning text from a full image that it can see if the source image is cropped. Is there a response limit?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-mlkit

I am using the Google ML Text Recogniser library in Android Studio for an Android app.

It is successfully returning a lot of text from a large image, but the specific, visible text I want it to return is not present in the result.

However, if I crop and save the part of the image containing the text I want, it returns it correctly, so I know the text in the original image is large and clear enough to be seen. I am not enlarging the cropped image.

I have eliminated the possibility of the result not being displayed fully, by reading the length of the full, returned text.

My questions are therefore:

- Is there a limit to the size and resolution of image that can be
  parsed by the ML Text Recogniser?
- Is there a limit to the amount of response text that is returned by the ML Text Recogniser?

I have not been able to answer these questions through searching.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE: I got around this by cropping the image up into an overlapping grid and parsing each section individually. I think the engine just gets overwhelmed on large images, so splitting it up into little ones gave me the text I needed.

Comment: There's no limit to the size of input image. I guess the image passed to ML Kit is not exactly same as what you can see. You can dump the images and compare.